# What timezone am I?

Tags: wordplay, time

It was 17:52 in the evening and I couldn’t wait for my class to finish. Only 8 more minutes… I really hate night school!

I sat there pondering the stuff on the blackboard and wondering why he wrote it only 8 minutes before class let out. It reads:

> Class, I have a quest ion: What time zone are we in?

Of course I know what time zone I’m in, so why would he be asking this.

Wondering if it was a trick question, I pondered over it.

Earlier in the class I couldn’t help but notice the professor had scribbled a note on the window:

> My cat needs food.

Curious, I wondered why he would put that for everyone to see.

While attempting to figure it all out, I get a text from a distant friend.

> Them: hey
>
> Me: hey! hows Vik?
>
> Them: <3 love
>
> Them: you eat dinner yet?
>
> Me: no, in class
>
> Me: you have breakfast yet?
>
> Them: yeah, ate at 8 (lol), 7 min ago
>
> Me: lucky, i'm starving

The professor looks around and taps on the blackboard to ensure everyone was working.

I then realize he is just as bored as we are and it’s not a trick question. He just wanted to keep us busy for the last few minutes… so I write down my current time zone and hand it in.

**Info**:

All times are standard, no daylight savings.

If you answer with the other one, it might just be correct.

**Edit**

After further research, I realize that the friend location is in one of those shared time zones despite the fact that it sits in another time zone. So, it might be a bit deceiving when looking at time zones.

Comment: So the space in "quest ion" is a typo?

Comment: @chux it is not

Comment: Hmmm,  so somehow "quest" next to "ion" fits into this puzzle - I do not see how yet.

Comment: @chux I actually explained it in the accepted answer comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> (UTC+8:45)

Reason:

> If the time is 17:52 for you, and 8:07 for your friend, the time difference is -9:45. The 45 minute timezone is very rare, so it is one of a few places. The text message says "how's Vik", there is a town in Iceland called Vik, and Iceland is UTC-1, so you are in Eucla, Australia (UTC+8:45).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not correct. There are clues to the actual GMT in the question, and the friend location

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Edited :)

Comment: This is correct :) Vik is actually +0, while it sits in the -1 time zone, it's actually +0. But I guess it just depends on what site you look at for reference

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker well I'm in England and I looked up Iceland timezone and it said 15:30 and it's 16:30 for me. I'm used to being UTC+0 as GMT but forget how DST affects that so just put -1 :)

Comment: I'm still confused by "My cat needs food" though, He wrote it on a window so I tried to write it down flipped, as if looking from the other side, but couldn't decipher it.

Comment: If you look at the blackboard it shows “quest ion” and not question. The clue was to get cation which a positive number, so + on the GMT

Answer (score 6):

You are in

> Nepal, UTC +5:45,

And your friend is in

> Eastern North America, UTC -4:00. At 8:07AM in Eastern NA, it will be 5:52PM in Nepal.

You could also be in

> Eucla, Australia, UTC +8:45, and your friend in Cape Verde, UTC -1:00.

You could also also be in

> Chatham Islands, New Zealand, UTC +12:45, and your friend in Turkey or Saudi Arabia, UTC +3:00.

Comment: One of these is correct but the friend location is wrong. It actually says where the friend is in the question :) Also, there are clues to the actual GMT

Comment: I have to stand corrected, the friend location is +0, not -1 GMT. My resources lied to me. So, your assessment for the -1 GMT is indeed correct.